# Surround with code tag using document.execCommand

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a custom WYSIWYG editor.

I have a content editable:

```
<div id='editor' contenteditable>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.toolbar a').click(function(e) {
    var command = $(this).data('command');
    if (command == 'h1' || command == 'h2' || command == 'p' || command == 'blockquote' || command == 'code') {
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, command);
    }

    if (command == 'createlink' || command == 'insertimage') {
        url = prompt('Enter the link here: ', 'http:\/\/');
        document.execCommand($(this).data('command'), false, url);
    }
    else
        document.execCommand($(this).data('command'), false, null);


});
```

My Toolbar:

```
            <div class="toolbar">
                <a data-command='undo'  href="#"><i class="material-icons md-dark md-36">undo</i></a>
                <a data-command='redo'  href="#"><i class="material-icons md-dark md-36">redo</i></a>
                <a data-command='bold'  href="#"><i class="material-icons md-dark md-36">format_bold</i></a>
                <a data-command='italic'  href="#"><i class="material-icons md-dark md-36">format_italic</i></a>
                <a data-command='underline'  href="#"><i class="material-icons md-dark md-36">format_underline</i></a>
                <a data-command='blockquote'  href="#"><i class="material-icons md-dark md-36">format_quote</i></a>
                <a data-command='code'  href="#"><i class="material-icons md-36 md-dark">code</i></a>
            </div>
```

Everything works, except the code tag. When I click the code button, nothing happens.

Note: The blockquote button works but code button doesn't do anything.

Comment: because there is no `code`support

Comment: Any work around then?